# how can I detect change or selection of new date - daterangepicker - JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, daterangepicker

I want to be able to access the event when if a user changes the date from the calendar and pass on this updated date to main controller.

my code is as follows

```js
$scope.cb= function(start, end){
  
   $('#dateRange span').html(start.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('MMMM D, YYYY'));
        startDateCal = start;
        endDateCal = end;
        if($('#sel_deviceType').length){
            type = $('#sel_deviceType').val();
        } else {
            type = "A";
        }
         $scope.loadChart(parseInt(start/1000),parseInt(end/1000), appKey, type);
    }

$scope.cb($rootScope.startDateCal,$rootScope.endDateCal);
// $scope.cb(moment().subtract(93, 'days'), moment());
    $('#dateRange').daterangepicker({
    ranges: {
       'Today': [moment(), moment()],
       'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
       'This Week': [moment().startOf('week'), moment().endOf('week')],
       'Last Week': [moment().subtract(1, 'week').startOf('week'), moment().subtract(1, 'week').endOf('week')],
       'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
       'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
},
locale: {
     format: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
     applyLabel: "Select"
},
startDate: $rootScope.startDateCal,
endDate: $rootScope.endDateCal
}, $scope.cb);
```

```html
<div id="dateRange">
```

Comment: Can you specify what plugin are you using for the the daterangepicker? There are like 10 separate plugins with different method names.

Comment: I am using daterangepicker - http://www.daterangepicker.com/ @SamuilPetrov

Comment: Using the "apply" event does not suit your needs?

Comment: @SamuilPetrov nope

Comment: after some research I am able to get the event 
' $('#dateRange').on('apply.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {}'

but how would I be able to get start and end dates ?!